# How does the quota limit for Google Civic Information API work?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-civic-information-api

I ask because the errors don't seem to line up with what the documentation says.

We have a daily limit of 1 million requests. Upon reaching about 995,000 requests, we started getting errors about hitting the limit and requests flat-lined. This happened around 7:20pm. The dashboard says "Daily quotas reset at midnight Pacific Time (PT)". However, requests started going through again at about 8:30pm.

Since 995,000 < 1,000,000 and 8:30pm != midnight, this leaves me with the feeling that we can't actually predict and prevent hitting the rate limit, or know when it will reset.

What do I need to know in order to do occasional heavy-use of the API while staying under the limits? Nothing in the documentation or dashboards gives me what I need.

Comment: I suspect this is only answerable by Google's support. Perhaps there are hourly/per-minute limits at play, and it's possible the number of requests shown is delayed or only updates every so often. If you're skating that close to the limits, it might be time to upgrade.

Comment: yeah... and google support has a link to posting here on Stack Overflow.
There is a limit of 5000 requests per 100 seconds - the graph of that limit showed that we were hitting around 2500 per 100 seconds. 

This was a case of purposely going close to the limit to do a one-time backfill of information. Our regular use is far lower. Though, I anticipate we'll want to do another process like this one when districts change and we want to get updated district info for our users. The goal is to get that done as quickly as possible while remaining below the limit.

Comment: https://cloud.google.com/support/#support-options

Comment: Late to the party, but the Support page linked above points out that we (GCP Support) monitor Stack Overflow. For a "how does it work" type of question like this we're happy to answer in public where more folks can benefit from the answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can see all your API quotas on the Google Cloud Console's "IAM & admin" page's "Quotas" tab. It should contain the details on how much you have used and whether or not you hit the limit. If you only used  995,000 / 1,000,000 and it show as such in your quota page (give it a bit of time to update since it might have delay) and it doesn't work, there's something wrong and should be reported to us directly.

I suspect you might be hitting a rate limit, which temporary prevented you from making further requests. You just have to bring your rate below the limit to have it working again. The quota page contain information on the rate limit (per 100 seconds) as well.

Your official support channels for Civic Information API is [here](https://developers.google.com/civic-information/docs/ci_forum).